# Smarter Autocapitalization

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I've been looking around, and I am wondering whether there is a simple way to capitalize all words in a `UITextField`, while leaving certain words (such as *of*, *the*, *or*, etc.) lowercase, unless they are the first word of the phrase.

This is an

> *Example of the Effect I'm Trying to Convey.*

One of the methods I've found is to search the text field value for the certain words and replace them with lowercase versions, as the user types a new word or character, perhaps listening for the space bar.

I'm not sure if the method above is best practice, or whether my searches haven't been broad enough to find a solution already in the mix.

I was originally thinking something along these "pseudocode" lines:

```
When value of textfield is changed
    Get current value textfield
    For each word in value:
        If the word matches ("For", "Of", "The", etc.) and the word is not the first word in the value:
        Change the word to lowercase, and replace word
    Go to next word
```

My actual question is mainly one of performance. Would this method be overly strenuous on my application? If so, are there any better solutions?

Thank you all for your assistance!

---

**Update:**

Thanks to holex, cluemein, and others who have already commented and answered. I will try your solutions when I get the opportunity to do so.

Comment: you may make changes only when certain characters typed like _space_; or you can count of the number of the _spaces_ and run the algorithm only when the number of the _spaces_ has changed etc... and – of course – when editing is finished.

Comment: What's your actual question? Do you need help with the rules of capitalization (off-topic) or do you need help with a specific programming aspect of this problem? Assuming the latter, what part? Have you decided when the capitalization will take place? As the user types the text or after the text field loses focus? Post what you have attempted so far and clarify what you need help with.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy for the advice/reminder on asking questions here. As I'm sure it's fairly easy to guess, I'm quite new at this, haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way then converting the words to lowercase is to capitalize the words that are ***NOT*** those words you specified.  Set up if statements to capitalize the beginning letter of the first word, and to capitalize the words following that if they are not the words you specified.  Then, if you want to make sure the specified words weren't capitalized after the first word, use an else statement.  "pseudocode" example:

```
Capitalize letter of first word;
Move on to next word;

While not end of textfield (or while typing):
     if word is not ("the"|"and"|"of"|"or"|...):
            capitalize first letter;
     else:
            set first letter to lowercase;
     move to next word at space;
```

This will on average be roughly twice as fast as going back through the text looking for the specified words in terms of runtime.  This isn't the code you would use, but the algorithm you would implement.  Also, take into account what holex said about spaces.  I leave how you implement this algorithm up to you.  Just to clarify, this algorithm is for both autocapitalizng and auto-setting to lower case.